# Dataframe groupby by paths in nested dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

DataFrame's groupby supports grouping by lists of columns in a table, eg given:

```
from pandas import DataFrame as DF

data2 = [{'a':{'x':1,'y':2},'b':2, 'x0':1},{'a':{'x':3,'y':4},'b':4, 'x0':3},{'a':{'x':1,'y':6},'b':6, 'x0':1}]
```

(For illustration, note 'x0' column duplicates the 'x' in the nested dict)

This works as intended:

```
DF(data2).groupby(['x0','b']).size().unstack()
```

[image]

How to emulate this behavior substituting the nested `'x'` for `'x0'`?

I've tried an approach using `lambda` to output a tuple:

```
DF(data2).groupby(lambda i: (data2[i]['a']['x'],data2[i]['b'])).size()

(1, 2)    1
(1, 6)    1
(3, 4)    1
dtype: int64
```

where `data2[i]['x0']` also works as the first tuple element. In both cases `unstack` throws:

`AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'remove_unused_levels'`

So the column/dict key names are not handled properly. Is there an in-place workaround, ie without setting new variables or DataFrames?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if you wanted to use a `lambda expression` you can but it is not going to be faster than your first approach:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data2).groupby(lambda i: (data2[i]['a']['x'],data2[i]['b'])).size()

# create a multiindex which will allow yo to use unstack
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index, names=['x0', 'b'])
df.unstack(level=1)

b    2   4   6
x0          
1   1.0 NaN 1.0
3   NaN 1.0 NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. I there a way to set the `MultiIndex` in-place without instantiating a new variable `df`?

Comment: You cannot set `pd.MultiIndex` inplace: you have to assign it to the existing variable `df.index`; however, it should be noted that you should should avoid `inplace` as it will be deprecated soon.

Comment: was not referring to `inplace`, but rather only whether it's possible to update `MultiIndex` without a new variable, so I called it in-place.

Answer (score 0):

Use pd.DataFrame.from_dict():

```
import pandas as pd

data2 = [
    {'a':{'x':1,'y':2},'b':2, 'x':1},
    {'a':{'x':3,'y':4},'b':4, 'x':3},
    {'a':{'x':1,'y':6},'b':6, 'x':1}
]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)
df = df.groupby(['x','b']).size().unstack()
print(df)
```

*output*

```
b    2    4    6
x
1  1.0  NaN  1.0
3  NaN  1.0  NaN
```

Comment: Charles R, you renamed `x0` as `x`, (I only used `x0` for illustration) so I don't think your method is a solution to this issue. What I want to work on is  `[
    {'a':{'x':1,'y':2},'b':2},
    {'a':{'x':3,'y':4},'b':4},
    {'a':{'x':1,'y':6},'b':6}
]`